# FB.ui({ method : "oauth" }) vs FB.login() within a Page Tab Application

Tags: javascript, facebook-page, facebook-oauth, facebook-login

We currently use the OAuth dialog via the JavaScript SDK within our page tab application to request permissions, instead of FB.login.

The reason for this is that FB.login() launches a new window, whereas FB.ui({ method : 'oauth' }) displays a nice looking modal dialog.  We find the OAuth dialog to be a much friendlier experience for our users.

However, the documentation for the OAuth method says not to use it directly within the JavaScript SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/
"The OAuth Dialog should not be called directly from the JavaScript SDK. Rather, use FB.login for this purpose."

***Is there an "accepted" way to request app permissions from within a page tab application via a modal dialog instead of via a popup window?***

Answer (score 1):

For the time of this answer Facebook does not allow user permissions to be requested in a frame because it sets 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. Which makes sense as it could be used for XSS proposes.

Calling either `FB.ui` or `FB.login` with `display: "iframe"` returns the same error:

`FB.ui({method: "oauth", display: "iframe"});`

`FB.login(function(response){}, {display: "iframe"});`

*Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=XXXX&channel=XXXX&sdk=joey' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.*